# Android, ImageView objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

thanks for reading. I'm making an app that can write musical scales based on input from spinners in the layout. I have 11 of Imageviews that take a LOT of information from a LOT of spinners, then those imageviews change on the click of a button in the layout. In short, I want to store the ImageViews in an ArrayList. This is my idea:

```
//Initilization of ArrayList as a member:
ArrayList<ImageView> pics;

//in onCreate():
pics = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
pics.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picA);
pics.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picB); //etc through picK

//in onClick():
for (int i; i++; i<11){
    if ("test".equals(noteArray[i]) pics[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.testPic);
    if ("testTwo".equals(noteArray[i]) pics[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.secondTestPic);
```

etc

But I am unable to use setImageResource() on pics[x]. It works fine on a regular ImageView object, am I using the ArrayList wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pics.get(i)`

`ArrayList` uses uses a function to get an object at a particular location.

Comment: So simple. Perhaps I shouldn't post on stackoverflow when I've a fever. I feel like I've wasted a question here. Either way, you were first and it worked fine, so I'll mark yours as best answer as soon as it lets me. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! You could have easily answered you own question with a little research but we all lose patients sometimes (especially when sick). If your are interested, when you feel better do a little research on the `Collections` interface